# Is there a way to pass information from the browser to a karma plugin?

Tags: javascript, karma-runner

I'm trying to develop a custom karma plugin reporter, but the docs are quite lacking. I have been able to get most of the plugin working by looking at other karma plugins, but one thing I can't figure out is how to pass information from the browser to the plugin.

I initially tried `window.__karma__.log()` and using `this.onBrowserLog()` in the plugin, but then any other karma reporters (e.g. `progress`) pick that up and also outputs that information, which greatly clutters up the console output from that reporter.

So is there a way to pass messages just to my reporter without other reporters outputting those messages?